# Unexplained DNS Routing Issue

Tags: domain-name-system

We have a site hosted on a dedicated server with other similar sites with similar or identical code. We have been experiencing intermittent outages, with the following symptoms:

- Successful pings
- Hop failures in traceroute
- Slow traceroute
- XML requests failing to post back
- Intermittent connectivity - some users ok, others finding the domain does not resolve.

All DNS checks seem healthy, global DNS checks resolve to the correct IP.

Does anyone know if this could be related to DNS problems with ISPs/networks and if there is any way to check this?

Comment: How can it be both that some users find the domain doesn't resolve and global DNS checks are okay? What does "intermittent connectivity" mean?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a routing issue. Can you elaborate on 'hop failures in traceroute'? Does tracroutes sometimes just fail, or do some hops not resolve to dns names?

You basically already answered your own question by mentioning that DNS checks resolve to the correct IP.

Comment: Yeah, sounds more like route flapping, or maybe a router somewhere having too much traffic to deal with..

Comment: Global DNS checks and pings return the correct IP. This isn't the same as a visitor being able to maintain a good enough connection to download a whole page. There is sufficient lag that the site becomes unusable, despite pinging successfully.

Comment: Traceroutes don't fail, the hops just increase in time (ie. hundreds not tens of ms) and hops fail - ie. timeout (* * *) but the trace eventually arrives.

What's particularly odd is that it's only for one domain, not even it's subdomains. I could understand a routing issue - but only if it affected all traffic to the server.

Comment: This defenetly rules out a DNS issue. The ping times increasing per hop indicate issues with that hop or the network from or to that particular hop. Not all traffic has to be affected, since routes from different clients can take different routes with different hops.